# From Clause not joining with 3 similar, yet works with 2

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have an irritating report being made in MS Access, and I'm having to make a query for a chart.

**PROBLEM**
My query uses 3 almost identical subqueries (just with different `WHERE` clauses) to output values to each of 3 columns. When I make it with 2 of the subqueries it works fine - however, as soon as the third is added, it gives me an error.

**Code so far:**

```
SELECT AllOpps.Week, AllOpps.WeekNum, AllOpps.TotalOpps As Total_Movement, 250000 AS TotalTarget, NewInv.Total AS New_Investigates
FROM(

    SELECT Format([OppMovs (Base)].DateTime,"ww mmm yy") AS Week, Sum([OppMovs (Base)].VALUE) AS TotalOpps, Val(Format([OppMovs (Base)].DateTime,"ww")) AS WeekNum 
    FROM [OppMovs (Base)] 
    WHERE Year([OppMovs (Base)].[DateTime])>=2020
    AND ([OppMovs (Base)].To LIKE '*1 Investigate*'
    OR [OppMovs (Base)].To LIKE '*2 Research*'
    OR [OppMovs (Base)].To LIKE '*3 Proposal*'
    OR [OppMovs (Base)].To LIKE '*4 Test*'
    OR [OppMovs (Base)].To LIKE '*5 Evaluate*'
    OR [OppMovs (Base)].To LIKE '*6 Implement*'
    OR [OppMovs (Base)].To LIKE '*7 Client*')
    GROUP BY Format([OppMovs (Base)].DateTime,"ww mmm yy"), Val(Format([OppMovs (Base)].DateTime,"ww")) 

) AllOpps RIGHT JOIN(

    SELECT Format([OppMovs (Base)].DateTime,"ww mmm yy") AS Week, Sum([OppMovs (Base)].VALUE) AS Total, Val(Format([OppMovs (Base)].DateTime,"ww")) AS WeekNo 
    FROM [OppMovs (Base)] 
    WHERE Year([OppMovs (Base)].[DateTime])>=2020
    AND [OppMovs (Base)].To LIKE '*1 Investigate*'
    GROUP BY Format([OppMovs (Base)].DateTime,"ww mmm yy"), Val(Format([OppMovs (Base)].DateTime,"ww")) 

) NewInv ON AllOpps.WeekNum = NewInv.WeekNo RIGHT JOIN (

    SELECT Format([OppMovs (Base)].DateTime,"ww mmm yy") AS Week, Sum([OppMovs (Base)].VALUE) AS Total, Val(Format([OppMovs (Base)].DateTime,"ww")) AS WeekNr 
    FROM [OppMovs (Base)] 
    WHERE Year([OppMovs (Base)].[DateTime])>=2020
    AND [OppMovs (Base)].To LIKE '*7 Client*'
    GROUP BY Format([OppMovs (Base)].DateTime,"ww mmm yy"), Val(Format([OppMovs (Base)].DateTime,"ww"))

) NewClients ON AllOpps.WeekNum = NewClients.WeekNr

ORDER BY AllOpps.WeekNum
```

**Error Message Given:**

> Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression 'AllOpps.WeekNum = NewInv.WeekNo RIGHT JOIN (
> SELECT Format([OppMovs (Base)].DateTime,"ww mmm yy") AS Week, Sum([OppMovs (Base)].VALUE) AS Total, Val(Format([OppMovs (Base)].DateTime,"ww")) AS WeekNr
> FROM [OppMovs (Base)]
> WHERE Year([OppMovs (Base)].[DateTime])>=202

Can anyone tell me why this is? I've tried differentiating the variable names, different kinds of joins, and so forth but don't really have a clue.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all those `RIGHT JOIN`s.  Just use conditional aggregation.  This pretty much does what your `RIGHT JOIN`s are doing:

```
SELECT Format([OppMovs (Base)].DateTime,"ww mmm yy") AS Week, 
       Sum([OppMovs (Base)].VALUE) AS TotalOpps,
       SUM(IIF([OppMovs (Base)].To LIKE '*1 Investigate*', [OppMovs (Base)].VALUE), 0) as Total_Investigate,
       SUM(IIF([OppMovs (Base)].To LIKE '*7 Client*', [OppMovs (Base)].VALUE), 0) as Total_Client
       Val(Format([OppMovs (Base)].DateTime,"ww")) AS WeekNum 
FROM [OppMovs (Base)] 
WHERE Year([OppMovs (Base)].[DateTime]) >= 2020 AND
      ([OppMovs (Base)].To LIKE '*1 Investigate*' OR
       [OppMovs (Base)].To LIKE '*2 Research*' OR
       [OppMovs (Base)].To LIKE '*3 Proposal*' OR
       [OppMovs (Base)].To LIKE '*4 Test*' OR
       [OppMovs (Base)].To LIKE '*5 Evaluate*' OR
       [OppMovs (Base)].To LIKE '*6 Implement*' OR
       [OppMovs (Base)].To LIKE '*7 Client*'
      )
GROUP BY Format([OppMovs (Base)].DateTime, "ww mmm yy"), 
         Val(Format([OppMovs (Base)].DateTime,"ww"))
```

Comment: Gordon, you're a genius. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access, you need parentheses around every subsequent join, like next:

```
select ...
from 
((t1
    join t2 on ...)
    join t3 on ...)
    join t4 on ...
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand? So which bracket would I remove from the line `) NewInv ON AllOpps.WeekNum = NewInv.WeekNo RIGHT JOIN (` for example?

Comment: You do not remove brackets, you add some - `SELECT ... FROM (( SELECT Format...` and `) NewInv ON AllOpps.WeekNum = NewInv.WeekNo) RIGHT JOIN (` for example